# Why is z-index affected by transform?

Tags: html, css, transform, z-index

So i have an icon you can flip when you click on the card. The icon is an element of the card div.

They have **the same animation** when they are flipping (see code below).

In the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5vdjp9ys/3/) the left card has a transformY when you click it, the right card has no transform at all. For showcase purposes I set the duration of the animation and transition to 2s so you can see what goes wrong in the left card. The z-index is totally different when you compare it to the icon in the right card.

I'd love to hear from you guys **WHY** this is happening, and I'd love to hear what I'm supposed to do to make it work correctly. Thanks!

```
/* FRONTFLIP */

@-webkit-keyframes frontFlip {
  0% {
    z-index: -1;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -25%) rotateX(-180deg);
    transform: translate(-50%, -25%) rotateX(-180deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -75%) rotateX(-270deg);
    transform: translate(-50%, -75%) rotateX(-270deg);
  }
  100% {
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotateX(-360deg);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotateX(-360deg);
  }
}


/* BACKFLIP */

@-webkit-keyframes backFlip {
  0% {
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotateX(-360deg);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotateX(-360deg);
  }
  50% {
    z-index: -1;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -75%) rotateX(-270deg);
    transform: translate(-50%, -75%) rotateX(-270deg);
  }
  100% {
    z-index: -1;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -25%) rotateX(-180deg);
    transform: translate(-50%, -25%) rotateX(-180deg);
  }
}
```

Comment: You can clear you concepts here .. http://zomigi.com/blog/css3-transitions-and-z-index/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the specification describes that a transform different than the value *none* should create a new [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context).

On MDN:

> If the property has a value different than *none*, a stacking context
>   will be created. In that case the object will act as a containing
>   block for position: fixed elements that it contains.